# pika.exceptions.ReentrancyError in pika python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

*File "C:venv\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1858, in start_consuming
'start_consuming may not be called from the scope of '*

***pika.exceptions.ReentrancyError**: start_consuming may not be called from the scope of another BlockingConnection or BlockingChannel callback*

Error occurred when using three threads. Only two channels created using one connection. But not able to create more channels using same connection.

Please suggest ways to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pika is not thread safe.  Without seeing any code it is impossible to give more detailed advice but each thread must have their own connection.

Comment: @Hannu, thank you for your suggestion and I guess this information will work for now.